# Understanding/creating a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to create a simple one way Linked List. I understand it conceptually but I'm stuck trying to create one. I know there are guides out there but I understand things better by trial and error.

My simple `Contact` class:

```
class Contact
{
    std::string name, phNum;

    Contact* next;

    public:
    void getInfo();
    void printInfo();
};
```

At this point, all I am trying to do is to create a list with some contacts (i.e. an address book of sorts), and then print out their information.

As per my understanding, the list should contain several unique objects of type `Contact`.

My question is, how can I create multiple objects in the heap that have unique addresses? I tried the below, but it obviously didn't work as all the pointers will be identical.

```
while(true)
{
    Contact* newEntry= new Contact;
    newEntry->getInfo();
    // rest of the linking stuff
}
```

Comment: "but it obviously didn't work as all the pointers will be identical" Why would you think that? `new` is not going to return the same pointer as any other still-valid pointer.

Comment: @bames53 It can return the same pointer, pointing to different memory. Maybe that's what's throwing him off. As you enter a different iteration of the loop, any old pointer will go out of scope.

Comment: I don't think either "trial and error" or "following a guide" is a good way to become good at programming. Rather, you should understand the abstract algorithms that drive linked lists, and understand how the language constructs work, and then implement the algorithm in the language based on your *understanding* of the two.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The only way to indicate two different locations is for the pointer values to be different. If the values are the same then they are indicating the same location in memory. `new` will not return the same value as any other still-valid pointer.

Comment: Do you really want to implement your own list? Maybe have a look a `std::list` or C++11's `std::forward_list`. I do not know how you want to use your Contact items, but maybe using another container would be better performancewise (e.g. using map or vector instead of list).

Comment: @bames53 I'm not saying the pointer doesn't have different values... A std::string can hold different strings, but still be the same object: std::string a = "first"; a = "second";.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That does not apply to the return values from `new`. `new` is not returning an lvalue. It's not true that `new` "can return the same pointer, pointing to different memory" because in the context of rvalues returned by `new` 'pointing to different memory' is equivalent to 'different pointer'.

Comment: @bames53 I'm saying the illusion of "same pointer" can be in the fact that the pointers reside in the same memory.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That's quite a bit different from saying that `new` can return the same pointer. Anyway, the variable the OP is storing the pointers in is scope limited to the loop, so whatever he does in the loop to check the pointers, printing them out or whatever, will show the unique pointers.

Answer (score 3):

To initialize many contacts in a loop you may want to do something like this:

```
Contact *FirstOne = new Contact();
Contact *current = FirstOne;
while(...)
{
    current->next = new Contact();
    current = current->next;
    //do stuff to current, like adding info
}
```

That way you are building up your Contact list. After that `*FirstOne` ist the first and `*current` is the last element of your list. Also you may want to make sure that the constructor sets *next to NULL to detect the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Okay just create a new contact and link it to the previous one. It looks like this conceptually.

```
object
   |
  Pointer to next one -> object
                           |
                           Pointer to next one -> object


Contact* newEntry= new Contact();     
newEntry->getInfo();     
newEntry->next = new Contact();
newEntry->next->getInfo();
newEntry->next->next = new Contact();
```